# Update column in related table with data from a join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables that hold data on physicians and the practices and health care organizations they belong to. For example ..

```
[Table Hmo]
╔════╦════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Id ║                Name                ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Purple Cross and Yellow Shield HMO ║
║  2 ║ Tifts Health HMO                   ║
╚════╩════════════════════════════════════╝

[Table Practices]
╔════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ Id ║ HmoId ║          Name           ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║     1 ║ Downtown Cardiac Group  ║
║  2 ║     1 ║ Tropical Medicine Group ║
║  3 ║     2 ║ Action SportsMed Group  ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════╝

[Table Physicians]
╔════╦═══════╦════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ Id ║ HmoId ║ PracticeId ║       Name       ║
╠════╬═══════╬════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  1 ║ ?     ║          1 ║ Dr. Trapper-John ║
║  2 ║ ?     ║          1 ║ Dr. Doolittle    ║
║  3 ║ ?     ║          2 ║ Dr. Smith        ║
║  4 ║ ?     ║          3 ║ Dr. Flintstone   ║
╚════╩═══════╩════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

I know the `HmoId` column is not necessary because the tables are linked by foreign keys, however, the user would neverthless still like to have this column populated. What I can't figure out is how to populate the `HmoId` column using an update query.

I can write a query to obtain the `HmoId` for each physician ...

```
SELECT Physicians.Name, Hmo.Name
FROM Physicians 
    LEFT JOIN Practices ON Physicians.PracticeId = Practices.Id
    LEFT JOIN Hmo ON Practices.HmoId = Hmo.Id
```

But how to translate that to an update query eludes me.

Comment: Either define a convenience view that includes the additional column(s) which users desire, or perform all queries using stored procedures that explicitly join to them at run time. I suggest you Google *Client Server* for the many reasons why this approach is recommended.

Comment: I understand why those approaches are better in the long run, but what I would like to figure out how this update would be written, regardless of whether it is the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Update p set 
p.hmoid = h.id 
FROM Physicians p
    LEFT JOIN Practices pr ON pr.id = p.practiceid
    LEFT JOIN Hmo h ON h.id = pr.HmoId
```